# Updating App ID for iCloud

Tags: xcode, app-store, provisioning

I saw a question similar to mine until I added for iCloud; however, the question did not seem to truly be in line with what I am thinking (but, could be wrong, and do apologize if I am).

The final section in the documentation (http://bit.ly/YhKXkX) entitled: Updating Your App to Include APNS, iCloud, In-App Purchase, or Game Center Requires an Explicit App ID - implies it is possible to take a current generic/wildcard App ID and alter to an explicit App ID. However, the documentation does not explicitly say whether doing so will cause the app to be considered a *new* app in the store; or, the same app with a different bundle identifier.

For example, if I have the App ID: ABCDEFG.* - and an app in the store using ABCDEFG as its bundle identifier - can I:

1. create an App ID of ABCDEF.explicit.app.ID *and*
2. replace the bundle identifier in my project with the new explicit ID *and*
3. submit the app to the app store as the same app which once had the bundle ID of ABCDEFG?

Memory of changing the bundle identifier a while ago says, "No. Once you have submitted to the store you must use the same bundle ID each time for an app to be considered the same app in the store" - but would appreciate verification.

Comment: wildcard ids arent usable with iCloud and gamecenter. The ABCDEFG. part is not by you and unrelated

Answer (score 0):

Under your app's target  -> Summary -> Bundle Identifier, you will see the app id. This can't be a wildcard app id. It has to be a unique ID.

Here's what you should do:
1. Create a new App ID that is the same as your Bundle Identifier
2. Enable iCloud for that app id
3. Create a new provisioning profile with that app id
4. Under Build Settings, make sure you change your code signing to the new provisioning profile you created.

You can now upload your app again and it will not be considered as a new app.

Comment: It does not let me create a new AppID that refers to the same BundleID and I get an error message in Dev Center that says this BundleID is not available.